# Placing road labels only at map edges and road intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, road

I want to place road labels only near the map edges, and where roads intersect - as depicted by the red X's in the image.

[image]

Background: I've seen the military do that in their topo maps, and I think it's a very efficient and clean way of labelling roads (these will be the 'shield-like' symbols with the route number in them) - maybe it's possible by using some kind of expression that detects the intersections between roads and map edges?

Comment: As one that has produced such military maps in a commercial environment I can tell you that we would create points, snap them to the lines and label the points. Label placement in this manner can (sort of) be scripted but in the end it's a cartographic ideal. If you want to write a program for creating likely label points I could give a few suggestions using end points, buffers and intersections...

Comment: I'm pretty new to QGIS (plus I'm not a programmer) so I wouldn't even know where to start reading to do something like that, but If you can give some suggestions that would be great.

Comment: I started with endpoints, buffered by a distance (and then again by a greater distance) then intersected (both) buffers with the lines which gave me a location (and alternate location) for the point... this will give you too many points but it's easier to delete a few points than it is to add. All of these tools are available in the QGIS toolbox.